# java.util.TimeZone DST Questions

Tags: java, dst

Whats the difference between  `java.util.TimeZone.inDaylightTime` and `java.util.TimeZone.useDaylightTime` in java ?

Comment: What does the documentation say the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

`inDaylightTime` checks if the specific timezone is in daylight time at the time specified as a parameter while `useDaylightTime` checks if the timezone ever has daylight time.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: Also Can the TZ files be incorrect in a lower java version say java 1.6 (update 24)  as compared to java 1.6 (update 43)?

Comment: I don't believe so as the method has been around for a long time (before Java 1.5)